# No mapping to a relational type can be found for property 'Identity.User.LockoutEnd' with the CLR type 'Nullable<DateTimeOffset>'

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-code-first-mapping

I want to create a migration for creating a new table in my database but after executing the `Add-Migration MsSql_Add_ArticleCategory_Table`, I got this error:

> No mapping to a relational type can be found for property
>   'Alpha.Models.Identity.User.LockoutEnd' with the CLR type
>   'Nullable'.

**How can I solve it (I've used asp.net core 3.1 iin my project)?**

> PM> Add-Migration MsSql_Add_ArticleCategory_Table Build started...
>   Build succeeded. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[30000]
>         No type was specified for the decimal column 'RateCounter' on entity type 'Article'. This will cause values to be silently truncated
>   if they do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly
>   specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values
>   using 'HasColumnType()'.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[30000]
>         No type was specified for the decimal column 'Rate' on entity type 'Rating'. This will cause values to be silently truncated if they
>   do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly specify the
>   SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values using
>   'HasColumnType()'. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
>         Entity Framework Core 3.1.3 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options:
>   MigrationsAssembly=Alpha.DataAccess  System.InvalidOperationException:
>   No mapping to a relational type can be found for property
>   'Alpha.Models.Identity.User.LockoutEnd' with the CLR type
>   'Nullable'.    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMappingSourceExtensions.GetMapping(IRelationalTypeMappingSource
>   typeMappingSource, IProperty property)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(IProperty
>   source, IProperty target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1
>   sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff,
>   Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(TableMapping
>   source, TableMapping target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1
>   sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff,
>   Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1
>   operations, DiffContext diffContext)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IModel
>   source, IModel target)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String
>   migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String
>   language)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String
>   name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String
>   name, String outputDir, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action) No mapping to a relational type can be found for property
>   'Alpha.Models.Identity.User.LockoutEnd' with the CLR type
>   'Nullable'. PM>

[image: No mapping to a relational type can be found for property]

**User Identity Model:**

```
namespace Alpha.Models.Identity
{
    public class User : IdentityUser<int>
    {

    }
}


namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
{
    public class IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
       public virtual DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
    }
}



namespace Alpha.DataAccess
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>(builder =>
            {
                builder.ToTable("User"); 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your model class to see which fields are causing trouble?

Comment: I added the User Model.

Comment: That's strange, I had no issue with a field of type `System.DateTimeOffset?`. Can you check that your `DateTimeOffset` is in fact coming from the `System` namespace? It might be that one of your using statement is pulling in a different one that can't be mapped by default.